# What is the difference between these to declaration types?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have the following code snippets in NodeJS with express:
1)

```
const app = express();
app.use('/index', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(INDEX);
})
app.listen(portno);
```

2)

```
const app = express()
  .use('/index', (req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX) )
  .listen(portno);
```

What is the difference between these two? 
 Why can't I use `app.use` command after the second declaration?
Also, why is the following code working only with the second one:

```
const Socket = require('ws').Server;
const server = new Socket({server: app});
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('New socket opened');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second case, the `app` variable ends up with what `.listen()` returns in it which is the `Server` object, not the app object.  Thus, when you then later try to do `app.use()` with the wrong thing assigned to `app`, it does not work properly.

Keep in mind that when you chain methods like this:

```
var x = a().b().c();
```

That `x` ends up assigned the return value of the last item in the chain.  Technically what happens here is that `a()` executes and on the return value from that, it looks for a `.b()` property to execute and then on the return value from that, it looks for a `.c()` method on that and then the return value from that is assigned to `x`.

So, in your case with:

```
const app = express().use(...).listen(...);
```

The `app` variable will contain the return value from `.listen()` which is a `Server` object, not an `app` object.  And, the `Server` object does not have the `.use()` method you were then trying to use with it.

You could instead do either of these:

```
const app = express().use(...)
app.listen(...);
```

Or:

```
const app = express();
app.use(...).listen(...);
```

Though, if you actually want to retain both the `app` and the `server` variables, most people will just do:

```
 const app = express();

 // define various routes and middleware
 app.use(...);
 app.use(...);
 app.use(...);

 // start the server
 const server = app.listen(...);
```